# How to display all pages continuously in Crystal Reports?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a question about Crystal Reports 2013.
I have a report with 11 - 13 pages data (dynamic). And I want to display all of them continuously / without any page break. So, I need to view next page just with *scrolling*, not with a button like *Next Page*.
Could you help me please how to do it in Crystal Reports 2013?

Comment: Can you try setting the paper size from your vb.net applications? So when you retrieve the data, you know already how many records you have, then you can calculate the estimate height required.

Comment: I thought that's not a good idea. Because I want a footer in every page.
Maybe you have another idea?

Comment: I thought you wanted to scroll continuously, which means that it's only one page, therefore there is only one footer, not in "every page".

Answer (score 1):

you can check this,

```
CrystalReportViewer1.SeparatePages = false;
```

Also check this link which say "Keep Togather" setting will help you.

http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=3196

http://scn.sap.com/thread/1649022(This is the last option I found)

**Updated**

I did not get any thing at crystal report side, the reason will be crystal report every time hit the db and execute whole code and redesign the page. So I don't think you can do this.

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/87668/Showing-all-pages-using-scroll-in-Crystal-Reports

http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=7852

http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=547

You can give the facility in export option as pdf, but not at crystal report side.

Comment: Ideally by the middle key of mouse if we scroll that will work same as you want. I did not get any thing at crystal report side,

Answer (score 0):

No, Crystal Reports won't allow to display many pages continuosly.

I understand that hitting "next page" and waiting for reload is annoying. You can programmatically export a report in PDF, so that Adobe Reader will show pages continuosly.

Answer (score 0):

peace be on you iwan,

please right click on CrystalReportViewer , tag
and see properties,
and set SeperatePages = False

my report pages are now continious without any break with scroll.

![enter image description here][1]

Comment: may i know which version CR that you're using?